# SQL Server Failover Cluster -- How to Fail Over Storage?

Tags: sql-server, clustering, failover

The picture helps explain what I am trying to do.

I know how to setup an SQL failover cluster, did it and it works perfectly.

Here is my situation : Node1 and Storage A is in one location (city) and Node 2 and Storage B is in a second location (different city).

Node 1 and Node 2 are connected to Storage A and Failover works perfectly.

NOW here is the catch.

How to setup so that if Storage A fails and I want to failover to Storage B.

I am wandering if its even possible since I have not found a single example on the net.

[image: SQL Failover Cluster]

Comment: or maybe you want want is known as a stretch cluster with storage replication ?
https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Server2016Storage/Storage-Replica-Stretch-Cluster-Complete-Walkthrough